# Why my form doesn't validate correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I'm trying to validate a form, but doesn't work :\ , When I submit the form goes to mail.php even if the required fields are missing, but I set `onsubmit` to `validate()` so it should check, but doesn't work. What's the problem with my code? I can't find it.

**HTML:**

```
<form action="mail.php" onsubmit="return validate()" method="post" class="contact-form" id="contactForm">

    <div id="errors"></div>

    <label for="author">Name:</label><br/><br/>

    <input type="text" name="author" id="message" /><br/><br/>

    <label for="author">Message:</label><br/><br/>

    <textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea><br/><br/>

    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Send Message"/>

</form>
```

**Javascript:**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function error(message){
        return "<p class=\"error\">"+message+"</p>";
    }

    function validate(){
        var form     = document.getElementById("contactForm");
        var author     = document.getElementById("author");
        var message = document.getElementById("messsage");
        var errors    = document.getElementById("errors");
        alert(author.value);
        if(message.value == '' || author.value == ''){
            errors.innerHTML = error("Please fill in all fields.");
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }

    }
</script>
```

Comment: You should never rely on client-side validation (ie. validation through JS without the equivalent validation on the server side). It is very easy to encounter a user who doesn't have JS enabled for whatever reason, and then there goes your validation.

Comment: Guys I fixed the HTML errors, now my document is valid, however it still doesn't works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var message = document.getElementById("messsage");
```

message has an extra "s".

```
<input type="text" name="author" id="message" />
```

You need to change "message" to "author"

Answer (score 3):

id=author on your first input element.

Also check out jQuery it will save you time in the long run

Answer (score 3):

You have two elements with the id `message` and none with `author`.

The [Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) would have picked this up for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
<input type="text" name="author" id="message" />
```

Need to set `name` and `id` to the same values (you're using `id="message"` for the next field, so there's a clash.

Also both your `label` tags have `for="author"`; the second one is wrong.

I guess your problem here is too much copy+paste.   ;)

Comment: You don't need to set `name` and `id` to the same value (in fact, when dealing with radio groups — you can't, since then you must have multiple elements with the same name)